# Really Maxima can't solve this?

Tags: math, algebra, maxima, equation-solving

I want to get inverse function of this: 
 -0.5*( (%e^(-4*x))*(%e^(2*x)+1

I tried:

```
ex1: -0.5*( (%e^(-4*x))*(%e^(2*x)+1) );
ex2: ratsimp(ex1);
ex2;
solve([y=ex2],[x]);
```

But Maxima return empty array.
Really Maxima can't solve this (Wolfram alpha can) or I do something wrong?

[image: Maxima input and output]

Comment: how is this related to programing?

Comment: I need some powerful CAS (computer algebra system) for my product...
I thought, that Maxima is strong enough, but it says the opposite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve exponential equation in Maxima CAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260551/how-can-i-solve-exponential-equation-in-maxima-cas)

Comment: As suggested by jacob, I also recommend trying the add-on package `to_poly_solve`.

Comment: FYI - `Derive for Windows` solves it as [four complex](https://i.imgur.com/ciqHNlE.png) expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to solve it with Python's [sympy](https://www.sympy.org). As sympy is not very fond of floating point numbers, I changed `* 0.5` to `/ 2`.

```py
from sympy import symbols, exp, solve, Eq

x, y = symbols('x y')
expr1 = -((exp(-4*x))*(exp(2*x)+1))/2

res = solve(Eq(y, expr1), x)
```

Result:

```
[log(-sqrt(-sqrt(1 - 8*y)/y - 1/y)/2),
 log(sqrt(-sqrt(1 - 8*y)/y - 1/y)/2),
 log(-sqrt(sqrt(1 - 8*y)/y - 1/y)/2),
 log(sqrt(sqrt(1 - 8*y)/y - 1/y)/2)]
```

To check, each of the results can be substituted back into expr1:

```py
for r in res:
    print(expr1.subs(x, r))
    print(expr1.subs(x, r).simplify())
```

This outputs 4 times `y` as the simplified expression:

```py
-8*(1 - sqrt(1 - 8*y)/(4*y) - 1/(4*y))/(-sqrt(1 - 8*y)/y - 1/y)**2
y
-8*(1 - sqrt(1 - 8*y)/(4*y) - 1/(4*y))/(-sqrt(1 - 8*y)/y - 1/y)**2
y
-8*(1 + sqrt(1 - 8*y)/(4*y) - 1/(4*y))/(sqrt(1 - 8*y)/y - 1/y)**2
y
-8*(1 + sqrt(1 - 8*y)/(4*y) - 1/(4*y))/(sqrt(1 - 8*y)/y - 1/y)**2
y
```

Comment: Thanks! But you want to say, that sympy is better than Maxima?

Comment: Are there any similar systems as sumpy written in python but only in javascript?

Comment: Interestingly, I tried OP's problem w/ `to_poly_solve` in Maxima and I get a somewhat different result, involving `log(sqrt(...))` but not `log(sqrt(sqrt(...)))`. I will try to look at whether these are actually the same later today.